# update_callback is not working in register_rest_field

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, wp-api

I am registering a new field in my custom post type using ***register_rest_field***.

But I am unable to add/update the field using the rest API of post add/edit. However, the get_callback function is working fine.

The sample code is like the below -

```
\register_rest_field('my_post_type', 'my_field', [
  'get_callback' => function ($params) {
    return \get_post_meta($params['id'], 'my_field', true);
  },
  'update_callback' => function ($value, $object){
    return \update_post_meta($object->ID, 'my_field', $value);
  },
  'schema'       => [
     'description'       => __( 'Array of the ids', 'textdomain' ),
     'type'              => 'array',
     'items'             => [ 'type' => 'integer' ],
  ],
]);
```

Thanks in advance!